# When setting up a contract, what do the fields mean?

Tags: account

When you set up a contract, you must provide, `manager`, `delegate`, `spendable` and `delegatable`.  What do these fields mean?

Answer (score 5):

- Manager : the keyhash (tz) of the account that can spend the money on the contract, if the contract is spendable, or change the delegate
- Spendable : is it possible to spend the money on this account without running any code (transfer money from this account)
- Delegatable : is it possible to change the contract by which all proof-of-stake activities for this contract should be performed
- Delegate : the contract that should perform all POS activities for this contract (can be changed later only if Delegatable)

(Updated thanks to Tom)

Comment: if there is a smart contract, can there be no manager, and transactions can only be done by function calls?

Comment: Two nits: Delegate is allowed even if not delegatable. Delegatable could be explained more clearly like spendable: whether the _manager_ can change the contract's delegate.